# Compare 2 rotated images that compose a 360 degrees image

Tags: rotation, screen-rotation, image-comparison

I would like to compare 2 images where 2nd image is a 60 degrees rotation of 1st image. Imagine that I have 2 snapshots captured from the same position (both compose a 360 degrees image) - but 2nd image is 60 degrees rotated to the 1st image.
I would like to find the common part (overlap in pixels) of the 2 images, as my final goal is to create a single panoramic image from these 2.

Is this possible? If so - how?

Answer (score 1):

The common way is to detect features in the two images and then match them (find which one exist in both images). This matching is done also usually using RANSAC as there will be outliers in the matches. See [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/01/11/opencv-panorama-stitching/) that shows how to do that in Python.

Comment: Thanks, will look into it.